# How do I receive Facebook notifications via the API when the newsfeed has changed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook graph api and c# sdk to make a desktop facebook application to notify users of new posts and messages in facebook. I can get the news feed (/me/home, in graph api talk), as well as messages, events, pokes, etc, but I have not been able to retrieve notifications such as when one of my friends "friends" someone else, or when one of my friends changes their profile picture. What does facebook call those notifications anyway? So, are those things available with the graph api? What about REST?

Answer (score 0):

You can do such things with Facebook Real-time Updates. You can subscribe to events on objects (user, page or permissions) and Facebook will monitor changes on these object and call a callback url when changes happen.

You can watch changes of fields (`name`, `email`, ...) but also connections (`friends`, `likes`, `inbox`, ...).

Let's say you subscribe to the `friends` connection real-time update for a user. Each time this user will have a new friend, a URL of yours will be called notifying you about the event.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That sounds like a really good solution except I am writing an application that many users will use to monitor their FB feeds. If I use callbacks, I would have to send them all to a server of mine, and I really don't want to do that. I was hoping that I could just use the api, as I am for the current feed, and also get information like when one of my friends adds a new friend, or likes something. Right now the feed object only gives status posts of my friends.

Comment: Hi MrGibbage, eventually, the same amount of data (all user data that you are interested in) will go from Facebook servers to yours, so there is no load increase with Facebook Real-time Updates. More over, it saves you to "ping" Facebook API every x minutes for new updates: Facebook will notify you when there is something for you. It seems that it is the best solution for you. What do you think ?